# Unescaped quote (') breaks Base64 in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to AES encrypt some data, and I use `random_iv` to generate an initialization vector.

```
def encrypt (data)
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CBC)
    cipher.encrypt
    cipher.key = @key
    iv = cipher.random_iv
    encrypted = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
    encoded = Base64.encode64(encrypted+iv) 
    return encoded, self.sign(encoded)
end
```

If `iv` contains `'`, the encoded string ends there and everything after `'` is ignored. I think `random_iv` is `OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(16)`, didn't check source yet. When I get `random_iv` like:

```
"0\xC8x'6\x86\x06\xFEG[\xCE\xF5\xF5\xCBL>"
```

the last 16 characters of the encoded string are nothing like it (end at `C8`).

```
Base64.decode64('1JCQvhD6mrDXkhW4Hn9HIIr32TmYlBmp803oxOtrZMg=\n')[-16,16]
# => "\x8A\xF7\xD99\x98\x94\x19\xA9\xF3M\xE8\xC4\xEBkd\xC8"
```

If there is no `'` in `iv`, it works fine. Right now, I'm solving this problem like this:

```
cipher.iv = Digest::MD5.new.digest(cipher.random_iv)
```

since `MD5` is `16byte` too, and fits the `iv` requirement.

```
Digest::MD5.new.digest('test').bytesize
# => 16
```

Wondering if there is any better way to do it. And why is there `'` in `random_iv` in the first place? How should I escape data passed to `encode64`?

Also, do I need to append bytes to my data until `data.bytesize` is divisible by `16`? Or does `Cipher::AES` do it for me?

```
cipher.update(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special about `'` as the contents of a string.  It's just a byte with ASCII value 39.

In the statement `encoded = Base64.encode64(encrypted+iv)`, `iv` is not the same variable as the `cipher.iv` you set two lines prior. Do you have a method or accessor in scope named `iv`?  Your base64 string `'1JCQvhD6mrDXkhW4Hn9HIIr32TmYlBmp803oxOtrZMg=\n'` (which I presume is the result of your function) does not end with the base64 encoding of your example iv, so I'm pretty confident the `+iv` part of the expression is not seeing `"0\xC8x'6\x86\x06\xFEG[\xCE\xF5\xF5\xCBL>"`.

The base64 encoding of your example iv successfully roundtrips for me:

```
irb> iv = "0\xC8x'6\x86\x06\xFEG[\xCE\xF5\xF5\xCBL>".force_encoding('BINARY') 
=> "0\xC8x'6\x86\x06\xFEG[\xCE\xF5\xF5\xCBL>"
irb> e = Base64.encode64 iv
=> "MMh4JzaGBv5HW8719ctMPg==\n"
irb> d = Base64.decode64 e
=> "0\xC8x'6\x86\x06\xFEG[\xCE\xF5\xF5\xCBL>"
irb> d == iv
=> true
```

Comment: Same here. I tried all sorts of different combinations of quotes and binary data and could not make it break. It seems quite strange if Base64 would be broken like this. Someone else would have noticed it a long time ago.

Comment: hi. yes in original code iv was same encoded as in definition, so my bad there...fiddled with things while posting here.

Comment: Anyway, I tested it and without .force_encoding('BINARY') its broken. With, it works fine.

Comment: In my environment, `#random_iv` returns a `<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>` string, as does `cipher.update(data)` even when `data` is UTF-8.  I only used `force_encoding` above because I was supplying the string as a literal which defaults to UTF-8.  Byte-strings (the result of any random byte generator or encryption method) should always be specified as BINARY encoding or you will get surprising results from methods interpreting them as unicode.